# Как добавлять данные в имеющуюся таблицу mysql

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate создаёт новую таблицу, а мне нужно, чтобы добавлял в существующую, как реализовать?

Вот код:

```
@Entity
    @Table
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        public String phone;
        public String message;

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setLastName(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для того, чтобы добавить данные в имеющую таблицу, необходимо было поправить строку:

> ```
> @Table(name = "НАЗВАНИЕМ ТАБЛИЦЫ", schema = "НАЗВАНИЕ СХЕМЫ")
> ```

Таблица - это то, куда записывать данные.

Схема - это то, где находится таблица.

Пример:

[image: Пример]

TestApi - название схемы, а ApiTable - названием таблицы.

2. Добавляем в `application.properties` вот такую строчку: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`
   и смотрим на то, какой версии наши зависимости,а точнее spring-boot, лучше всего иметь от 1.4.3 и выше.
3. В `application.propperties` добавляем строку

   `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`